# Create multiple columns from single column with complex logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am bit confused by all the apply, applymap, map stuff for Dataframes and/or Series. I want to create multiple columns derived from one column in a dataframe through a function which does some webscraping stuff.

My dataframe looks like this

```
>>> df
          row1        url    row3
0        data1  http://...    123
1        data2  http://...    325
2        data3  http://...    346
```

the webscraping function is like this

```
def get_stuff_from_url(url: str):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data1 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'stuff1'})
    data2 = soup.find('span', {'class', 'stuff2'}).text
    data3 = soup.find('p', {'class', 'stuff3'}).text

    return data1, data2, data3
```

The result should be

```
>>> df_new
          row1        url    row3       row4       row5       row6
0        data1  http://...    123  newdata1a  newdata2a  newdata3a
1        data2  http://...    325  newdata1b  newdata2b  newdata3b
2        data3  http://...    346  newdata1c  newdata2c  newdata3c
```

where newdata1 comes from data1 and so on.

My previous attempt (where `get_stuff_from_url` only returned one value) was

```
df_new = df_old['url'].apply(lambda row: get_stuff_from_url(row))
```

but this seems wrong and I can't extend this to multiple columns output. Any ideas to solve this in the way how it is meant to be?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Help us to help you - It is much more easy to reproduce an issue, while you provide data in a form that allows to simply create a dataframe. So try to provide also the result of  `df.head().to_dict()` in future. Would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `dict` in your `def` and use `.join()` to `.apply` the series:

```
df.join(df.url.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_stuff_from_url(x))))
```

So we use the value of `url` column for each row to call the `get_stuff_from_url()`, while `pd.series()` helps us to unpack the returned `dict` to following `DataFrame`:

|  | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |
| 1 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |
| 2 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |

Now a simple `df.join()` is sufficient to fit our needs and put both `DataFrames` together and final result.

|  | row1 | url | row3 | data1 | data2 | data3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | data1 | http | 123 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |
| 1 | data2 | http | 325 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |
| 2 | data3 | http | 346 | stuff1 | stuff2 | stuff3 |

###### Example

Just to demonstrate how it works, simply use your inital `def` and adapt it to store the scraped data in your `dict`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'row1':['data1','data2','data3'],
                   'url':['http','http','http'],
                   'row3':[123,325,346]
                  })

def get_stuff_from_url(url: str):
    # response = requests.get(url)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data = {
        'data1': 'stuff1', #soup.find('div', {'class': 'stuff1'})
        'data2': 'stuff2', #soup.find('span', {'class', 'stuff2'}).text
        'data3': 'stuff3'  #soup.find('p', {'class', 'stuff3'}).text
    }
    return data

df.join(df.url.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_stuff_from_url(x))))
```

Comment: Elegant. Hadn't thought of using a `dict`. Makes a lot of sense. Small correction last line: `df.row3` should be `df.url`.

Comment: @ouroboros1 : Definitely it should be `url`, thanks for pointing that out, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is a nice solution! My understanding is that
```get_stuff_from_url``` has input: **string** and output: **dict with data for one line*;
```lambda function``` input: **string (from one line)** and output: **pd.Series containing data of one line**; 
```apply function``` on/"input" **dataframe** and returns **dataframe with all lines** and multiple columns. Is there any overview what the function passed to df.apply is allowed to return and how this is handled within the apply function? I didn't know that returning a pd.Series with multiple columns is even allowed here.

Comment: Edited the answer to clarify - Main point here is to understand that we just `apply` and not `assign`. Behaviour becomes visible if you simply make the following `df.url.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(get_stuff_from_url(x)))` you get a `dataframe` there is nothing assigned to our original one. that is what the join makes.

Answer (score 5):

**Problem.** We have a df that contains a column with urls. We want to create a soup for each of these urls, then return 3 values from the created soup and populate the rows of 3 new columns with the returned values.

**Solution.** Here's a simplification of your function:

```
def get_stuff_from_url(url: str):
    # response = requests.get(url)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    data1 = '<div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>'
    data2 = "Hello world"
    data3 = "Right back at you, sir!"

    return data1, data2, data3
```

This function returns multiple values. If we assign it to one variable, this variable will now contain a tuple. Suppose we wrote:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df['url'].apply(lambda row: get_stuff_from_url(row)))
```

Then we would end up with a df with just 1 column, each row containing the same tuple: `('<div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>', 'Hello world', 'Right back at you, sir!')`.

If we want to populate multiple columns with the elems from the tuple, we can use [zip(*iterables)](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip), where we use the `*` operator to unzip the tuple passed to `zip()`.

To create a new df using this method you could do:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(zip(*df['url'].apply(lambda row: get_stuff_from_url(row)))).T
```

Result:

```
                                        0            1                        2
0  <div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>  Hello world  Right back at you, sir!
1  <div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>  Hello world  Right back at you, sir!
2  <div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>  Hello world  Right back at you, sir!
```

If you simply want to add the data to your existing df, you could do:

```
df['data1'], df['data2'], df['data3'] = zip(*df['url'].apply(lambda row: get_stuff_from_url(row)))
```

Let's print the first row to see what we end up with (`print(df.iloc[0])`):

```
row1                                      data1
url                                  http://...
row3                                        123
data1    <div class="stuff1"><p>Stuff</p></div>
data2                               Hello world
data3                   Right back at you, sir!
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Well explained the issue of original returned data and how to handle it - also quite nice solution.